# How to make a custom LED backlight

Tags: led, lighting

I would like to make one of these edge-lit LED backlights, with a custom shape:

[image: LED backlight]

Although I have tried searching, I can't seem to find exactly what materials it's made from.

Are these just a sheet of perspex with a white backing and some LEDs in the edge, or is there some special material I need to make it work well? What keywords should I be using in my search to find the right materials?

Comment: While light guides are common, I have one that uses a frosted front panel and a 5 X 20 array of 100 LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods I knew of:

- Using a white reflector sheet just like in most small-size (e.g. 10") LCD panels.
- Using a Light Guide Panel and a diffuser.

The latter is a quite common method for homogeneus lighting panels for, for example, corridor lighting. You can see the examples in 60cm x 60cm lighting panels in some hospitals' ceilings. Basically a guide (LGP) is a unidirectional, transparent or semitransparent panel that "guides" the light coming from only two opposite edges so that the light goes outwards the panel *(Interestingly, it does not work if the light comes from the other opposite edges)*. If you google "light guide panel" you can find lots of info and purchasing options.

Using perplex is more common in those transparent, aesthetic, funky signboards :)

Answer (score 1):

This kind of backlight (light guiding material, or LGM) has a back surface with a micro mirror pattern that redirects edge-light toward the front. You can obtain this material from plastics suppliers or go to the manufacturers directly.

Examples:

Brightview: https://www.brightviewtechnologies.com/products/display/edge-lit

Acrylite: https://www.acrylite.co/products/our-brands/acrylite-led/light-guiding-edge-lit-sheet//

Evo-lite: https://www.evo-lite.com/product-line/lumisheet-led-light-panel/

There are many others...

Answer (score 1):

There was a [post on Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/2023/03/13/a-hackers-introduction-to-diy-light-guide-plates/) describing how to make custom backlight panels.

In short, this is called a "light guide plate" and it's just acrylic. However, it has to be specially engraved to emit light uniformly.